# Testing Rails 4 Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm having some trouble understanding what my be wrong with my test, but I keep getting No Route Match when testing the update method for a controller. Submiting a form through a browser works, though.

My Routes file:

```
namespace :merchant do
    resources :users
    get '/signup', to: "users#new"
 end
```

My Controller:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @merchant_user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @merchant_user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'show' }
      format.json { render json: @merchant_user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My Test:

```
test "should update user" do
   user = users(:jon)
   user.first_name="Jonas"
   put :update, :merchant_user =>user.attributes
   assert_response :success
```

end

Result:

```
1) Error:
Merchant::UsersControllerTest#test_should_update_user:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:merchant_user=>  {"id"=>"846114006", "email"=>"jon.sims@whatever.com", "first_name"=>"Jonas", "last_name"=>"Sims", "password_digest"=>"$2a$10$LVbV7pkd7li8sobYEauoS.4JVA2ZHzAXgPFbyiojYqgcDBHUE9bXW", "type"=>"Merchant::User", "created_at"=>"2013-07-11 22:59:41 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2013-07-11 22:59:41 UTC"}, :controller=>"merchant/users", :action=>"update"}
test/controllers/merchant/users_controller_test.rb:45:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way your routes look it seems like it's expecting an `id` parameter.

If you do `rake routes` from the command line it will probably show a route that looks like

`/merchant/users/:id/update`

If you pass in the `id` like this `put :update, id: user.id, merchant_user: user.attributes` it should work.

Comment: Will test later, but seems that may be the problem from a newbie picking up again on Rails :).

Comment: That was that. Thanks Mohamad and Leo Correa. Though both helped me, I will accept Leo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the `id` of the user for the test to run correctly.

Try this:

```
put :update, id: user.id, merchant_user: {}
```

You're seeing this error because the router expects `resource/:id`, but your are not passing the id.

`Users#update` is a member action, which requires an id. The router expects a user id param: `/users/:id/update`. Without the id the method has no way of finding the user you want to update.